# CakePhp 2 prevent ajax if checkbox is marked

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.3

I need to mark one checkbox named brandId,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lastBrandId" id="lastBrandId" value="1">
```

When I mark the checkbox I trigger another jQuery to bring back and populate the serial number field:

```
<input name="data[Brand][serialNumber]" type="text" id="serialNumber">
```

If the checkbox is marked I do not want the cakephp 2 get method below to be triggered:

```
   echo $this->Js->get('#BrandId')->event('change', $this->Js->request(
        $ajaxUrl,
        array(
            'update' => '#form-ajax',
            'evalScripts' => true,
            'before'=>"$('#loading').show();",
            'complete'=>"$('#loading').hide()",
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => false, 'inline' => true)),
            'dataExpression' => true,
        )
    ));
```

I can not see which variable I can use in this case. Can I enclose the php code with JavaScript code?

I try the php code enclosing the cakephp ajax request, but did not stop the ajax request:

```
if(!empty($this-request-data['lastBrandId']))
```

There is any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it, but perhaps you could use (formatted to see the logic):

```
'before'=>"
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   return false;
} else {
   $('#loading').show();
   return true;
}",
```

The idea is that return false should stop the ajax call.

I personally moved away from using the JsHelper. External .js files are easier to debug and can be minified.